# php snippets not working in sublime text 2?

Tags: php, code-snippets, sublimetext2

I am trying to set up sublime text 2 with PHP, but I am having some trouble getting the snippets to work. I have loaded a PHP project and see that the syntax is correctly set to PHP. When I go to preferences -> browse -> packages _>php , I can see a number of PHP snippets that I am unable to activate including $_files $_get ,$*post. As far as I can tell, the tab trigger for these are '$*_'

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[\$_COOKIE['${1:variable}']]]></content>
<tabTrigger>$_</tabTrigger>
<scope>source.php</scope>
<description>COOKIE['…']</description>
</snippet>
```

but this does not generate any snippets being displayed, when I try it in a php file.

Can anyone give me advice on what to do next?

Thank you,

Bill.

Comment: I've done this twice now - Just leaving a note for future people who may come across this. Make sure the spelling on the file name is correct, e.g. it ends in `.sublime-snippet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works on my Sublime Text 2, but only within the `<?php ?>` tags, not just in a file called .php.

Typing "$_ + TAB" within `<?php ?>` tags gives a list of all the $_ Snippets COOKIE, FILES, ENV, etc...

My next steps would be:

- Do other Snippets work?
- Did you create a Snippet that could overrule the $_ ?
- Re-install ;-)

Comment: when I reinstalled it started to work - ? - I'm not sure why. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You enabled the source for php, you can only be call this snippet in your php file only.

1. create new file and save as `somename.php`
2. write `<?php` after
3. type `$_` and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd>

It generates the snippet, lets happy coding.